# How do I detach a system added to my Ubuntu pro subscription?

Tags: server, ubuntu-pro

I have 3 machines attached however I can only find 2 on my estate, is it possible to detach a token from the portal or get a list of machines? its possible the other server has been decommed and I would like to release that token.

Comment: If a Ubuntu-Pro machine isn't used for a *period of time*, it'll get *dropped* from the count of connected machines; alas I can't recall where I read/heard that, or if a time-period was provided before the *dropping* occurs was specified, but if I wanted to look for details I'd probably go to the FAQ first - https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-pro-faq/34042

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have checked the docs and unfortunately can't see anything. I have logged a support ticket so will update in this thread when I get the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you visit https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard there it will show you all the active systems you have attached at the time.  If you mouse over the `i` next to the number of "Active machines" it shows you the following message:

> The number of machines with this token that contacted Ubuntu Pro in
> the last 24 hours (Beta)

[image]

Which means that any system that you have decommed there is nothing more to be done on your side as after 24 hours it will leave your account as being an active machine.  I have gone through many Ubuntu LTS installations over the years and not once have I ever had a need to actually try to remove it from my account as it has fallen off after the 24 hour period.